# Footer ~ Positioning//With a twist

Tags: html, css, positioning, footer

So I took use of the 'Sticky Footer' code which automatically places the footer below all of the content, my problem is that my content height is set to 1300 pixels, meaning if you have a screen with a height more than 1300 pixels the footer will not appear at the bottom of the screen but rather below the content.

Here's my code:

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Mono';


body {
    font-family: 'PT Mono', monospace;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1D4350 , #A43931);
    background-attachment: scroll;
}
#content {
  height: 1300px;
  width: 100%;
}
html, #wrapper {
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 960px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.Octagon { 
    color: #2aa186;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30%;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.LT {
    text-align: center;
    color: #3a5454;
    line-height: 0%;
    font-style: italic;
}
.boi {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding: 8px 18px;
  border: 1px solid #204156;
  border-color: #52AEC9;
  color: #52AEC9;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}
.boi:active {
    top: 2px;
}
.iob {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding: 8px 18px;
  border: 1px solid #204156;
  border-color: #52AEC9;
  color: #52AEC9;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
}
#verr {
    
}
.boi:active, 
.iob:active {
    top: 2px;
}
#manyarms {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 31px;
}
#sensible {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 31px;
    right: 10px;
}
.boi:hover,
.iob:hover {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #a193ff;
}
#footer {
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
        <title>The Pragmatic Octopus</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
     <script src='script.js'></script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
     <h1 class="Octagon">The Pragmatic Octopus</h1>
     <p class="LT">Lee Townsend</p>
        <a href="www.google.com">
     <p class="boi">Contact</p>
        </a>
        <a href="www.google.com">
     <p class="iob">Information</p>
        </a>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="manyarms">
        <img src="https://s32.postimg.org/406x38nlh/imageedit_1_3827627792        .jpg" alt="mmm~" style="width:310px; height:250px;">
        <p style="color: #6458b7;" id="verr">Here comes a very special boi!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="sensible">
        <img src="http://www.wonderslist.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Blue-ringed-octopus.jpg" alt="~mmm" style="width:310px; height:250px;">
        <p style="color:#6458b7;">He loves to pose for photos!</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
      <div id="footer">
      &copy; Hecc
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I apologize if my wording makes this problem difficult to visualize.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: ALSO: Is there any way for me to get my captions for the image closer to the bottom of said image?

Comment: So, you want your footer to always appear at the bottom of the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little ambiguous - I think you are asking "how do I fix my footer to the bottom of the screen (window), not below the content?".

You can use position fixed for that.

```css
article {
  height: 1300px;
}
footer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: lightpink;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <article>
    <p>This is the page content</p>
  </article>
  <footer>
    <p>I am a fixed footer</p>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem and helped me solve other positioning problems I had.